# PowerDesigner - Prevent DB name to be uppercase in generated SQL

Tags: sybase, powerdesigner

I am currently beginning playing around with Sybase PowerDesigner and its Physical Data Model (PDM).

I have managed to create some entities/tables, columns, et cetera, and the case in the generated SQL (to create the database from the model) is like I want.

However, regarding the database name, PowerDesigner insists for it to be always in uppercase. Actually, I am not getting any error message or anything like that and I'm actually allowed to type in a mixed-case database name but as soon as I close the "Model Properties" window and come back to it to check, the database code name is back to uppercase.

I obviously unticked the "=" button connecting the logic name to the code name so I can type a different code name, but it still doesn't work (while it does for tables).

Is there any way to have a database name in the generated SQL script corresponding to the case I specified in PowerDesigner? The DBMS type is SQL Server 2008 (tried previous versions and the problem is the same).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 21):

I found how to do it:

1. Right-click on an empty spot in the model area.
2. Select "Model Options..." from the context menu.
3. Select "Naming Convention" from the tree.
4. Select "Code" from the tab group.
5. Select "Mixed case" beside "Character case".
6. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on an empty spot in the model area.
2. Select "Model Options..." from the context menu.
3. Select "Naming Convention" from the tree.
4. Select "name to code" check "Apply name to code convertion"